# Have Admin access but cannot login to Sql Server 2016 reporting services configuration manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, configurationmanager, ssrs-2016

I am trying to access the reporting services configuration manager. I have admin access. When I open the server I am able to login and select the instance, but when I try to access any of the tabs I am getting the following error:

```
There was an error while switching panels. The most likely cause is an error retrieving
WMI properties. The exception details are:

Access is denied. You must be an administrator on the Report Server computer to use this tool.
```

Comment: Hi Divya, try opening the tool as 'Administrator'..

Comment: Add the error message as a text.

Comment: I am getting the following error:
unhandled exception has occurred in your application. if you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue, if u click quit the application will close immediately
I clicked Continue then I got another dialogue box with the following error:
There was an error while switching panels the most likely cause is an error retrieving wmi properties:
The exception details are Access is denied. You must be an administrator on the Report Server Computer to use this tool.